# Escape a period when making a Table of Contents in Markdown on Github

Tags: github, markdown

Currently I am making a table of contents for a file that is in markdown. When I upload it to GitHub, the link does not work.

One of the links in the table of contents is:

```
[myAPI.APIExample](#myapi.apiexample)
```

How do I escape the period character in this?

I have tried using "\" and "\\" and neither of these have worked.

Comment: How does it "not work"? In other words, what behavior are you trying to avoid? Could you edit your question to include the HTML generated by GitHub? You may use your browsers "view source" feature to find the HTML, or you could point us to the project if it is public. Ideally, it would be helpful to also include the HTML you expect to have been generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question. The correct way is to completely remove the period.

```
[myAPI.APIExample](#myapiapiexample)
```